# pandas: join two dataframes 2 dataframes creates more rows than expected

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe

I am using the join operator two join two dataframes on a specific column as reference. 
I joined them based on the Time column which is in datetime format and in the same format as the index column of the other dataframe (which is datetime index column).
The shapes of the dataframes are:

```
df1.shape = (21678,7)
df2.shape = (20634,200)
df3= df1.join(df2, on = 'Time (CET)', how = 'inner')
```

So I expected the outcoming shape(df3.shape) should be (20634,207). Surprisingly the shape of the joined dataframe df3 is (20636,207). Any suggestions how this can happen? 
Thank you :)

Comment: Do you have duplicate values in 'Time (CET)' in either dataframe?

Comment: How can I check this in a quick way? (I did not check this)

Comment: @inneb If `df1[df1['Time (CET)'].duplicated()]` or  `df2[df2['Time (CET)'].duplicated()]` isn't an empty dataframe.

Comment: `print('DF Length: {}   Unique Values: {}'.format(len(df1), df1['Time (CET)'].nunique()))`

That would be one way. If you have fewer unique values than total rows, then you have duplicates. To find the duplicate rows you can do `df1.loc[df1['Time (CET)'].duplicated()]`

Comment: @EFT thanks a lot guys I will check it out :)

Comment: 7131  2015-10-25 02:00:00   
   16036 2016-10-30 02:00:00
It prints out those two lines, so this means the two of them are duplicates or they have a duplicate?

Comment: Ok I got the probleme. It is because there is somehow a different style how to work with the change from summer to winter time :D